# Installing SBT with OJDK Java version 9

Tags: java, scala, java-9

When I try to run `sbt update`, I get the following in the log-file.

```
WARN:   [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.12!main.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (1139ms)
```

and the following error message:

```
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/brett/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.12
```

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Scala version

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
```

How can I fix the issue. I don't see any way around this on the web.

Comment: it's still months until the java9 release, so i wouldn't expect support to be in stable versions of anything and even nightly versions may or may not be ready for it. so... try the latest nightlies?